# How can I display keyboard shortcuts as I press them?

Tags: software-recommendation, shortcut-keys

I'm going to be giving a short "talk" about efficient note taking with LyX. As such it'll be important to focus on keyboard shortcuts. Since people can't see me type, however, I want a tool that displays keyboard combinations as I press them, like this:

[image: "Yo dawg, I done press Ctrl-M", written in a corner while I use LyX]

I'm *sure* I've read about something like this on OMG Ubuntu!, but my google-fu is weak.

Ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### [Screenkey](https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey)

> Screenkey is a screencast tool to display your keys inspired by Screenflick for Mac OS and based initially on key-mon project.
> It’s useful to create screencasts and is also a powerful teaching tool.

```
sudo apt install screenkey
```

For older versions of Ubuntu you can download [screenkey .deb file](http://launchpad.net/screenkey/0.2/0.2.0/+download/screenkey_0.2_all.deb) from launchpad directly.

[image: screenshot]

The [original project by Pablo Seminario](https://launchpad.net/screenkey) (2010-2012) is no longer maintained.

Comment: This did the trick :) Bonus points for Python.

Comment: Current repo version is old (0.9). To close it: [`pkill -f screenkey`](https://superuser.com/a/1345082/500826)

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post but still well referenced.

Here a 2020 update:

- [screenkey](https://www.thregr.org/%7Ewavexx/software/screenkey/) is still maintained but is not really useful for most screencast tasks.
- [kmcaster](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/kmcaster/) is also actively maintained, is not packaged, but the packaged .jar should run on ubuntu. and it shows what most people would expect.

Comment: kmcaster is indeed a good recommmendation. The JAR file is hidden in the middle of the page at "Download", and requires most recent Java JRE versions.

Comment: 2024-03: kmcaster link dead. Try xev, see here https://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux