# Visualize pressed keys onscreen

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard

I want to show others what keys I currently press onscreen. Unfortunately, neither xvkbd nor florence nor onboard visualize the keys I press. What else can I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I display keyboard shortcuts as I press them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30466/how-can-i-display-keyboard-shortcuts-as-i-press-them)

Answer (score 5):

[**Screenkey**](https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey) works well, although it shows a banner instead of a full virtual keyboard (and sometimes misses keys, but that may just be a bug):

[image: screenshot of screenkey]

Comment: https://gitlab.com/screenkey/screenkey <- not sure if the launchpad link is updating from here

Answer (score 4):

According to [alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net), screenkey is a no longer maintained dead project.

For my screencasts I use [key-mon](https://github.com/scottkirkwood/key-mon) and works pretty nice. It shows only pressed letter and special buttons and mouse. Here's a photo:
[image: key-mon photo]

Comment: New link for key-mon: https://github.com/scottkirkwood/key-mon