# Certain key combinations are not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, laptop

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on HP Laptop.

I'm experiencing some issues with certain key combinations in my laptop keyboard.

Following key combinations are not working.

- Right Shift Key + E
- Ctrl + C

Ctrl + other keys are working, also, c is working independently. Right Shift + other keys are working. Left Shift + E is also working.

Can anyone help me to identify if it is a configuration issue or an indication of an upcoming hardware failure?

I have used some diagnosis tools and identified these combinations ar re not detected. Would it be a hardware issue when these keys are working independently and in combination with other keys.

Answer (score 1):

To assess whether the keyboard is failing, you could use any application to monitor key presses.
See options [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197651/ubuntu-show-what-keys-are-pressed-in-real-time), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30466/how-can-i-display-keyboard-shortcuts-as-i-press-them), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/248517/show-keys-pressed-in-linux):

1. `screenkey`
2. `sudo evtest`
3. `xev`

You can perform further evaluations by:

1. Booting from a Live USB and/or Windows. If the problem stems from your Ubuntu configuration, these should work.
2. Using another keyboard in your Ubuntu.

All this should suffice to give a clear answer.

**Related**

1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LaptopTesting/Keycodes
2. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/showkey.1.html

Comment: I have used these tools and found above key combinations are not detected. Would it be a hardware issue when these keys are working independently? and with other keys? Just these combinations are not working.

Comment: Try in a live session. If they work there you can rule out hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the tools suggested in the other answer, and found the mentioned key combinations are not detected, even though they are detected independently.

I tried pressing the keys a little bit harder, and now the key combinations are working.

So, I think there was some contact issue in the keyboard because of dust.