Changing the focused Firefox tab using Alt+Number crashes the browser
Changing the focused Tab on Firefox using Alt+Number crashes the browser.

Are you using Firefox snap or dpkg?

I cannot reproduce that with the snap version of Firefox.

It's the one that came with the installation. I believe it's snap.

I cannot reproduce that with either version (124 nor 127) of firefox. Both are manually installed.  Tried locally and via remote session.

Cannot reproduce on esr version (.deb).

I found the issue. It has something to do with my keyboard. The F4 key is being pressed every second without my control. I am trying to cancel this key and asked how to do it in Wayland here: How to cancel the F4 key on Ubuntu 22.04 (Wayland)

To check your keyboard, perhaps this would help  https://askubuntu.com/questions/30466/how-can-i-display-keyboard-shortcuts-as-i-press-them
